# Azure DevOps: Error when secret contains double and single quotes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I read from the Azure Key Vault a secret as follows and want to pass the content as an output variable.

```
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'Azure'
      KeyVaultName: 'kv'
      SecretsFilter: 'XXX'
      RunAsPreJob: false

  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'echo $(XXX)'

  - bash: |
      WI=$(DB-WORKSPACE-INFO)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;isOutput=true;]$WI"
```

The problem is, that the key contains `'` as well as `"` and so I get

> unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

How can I handle that?

**EDIT**
Based on @Jessehouwing suggestion I changed the script to

```
  - bash: |
      echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;isOutput=true;]$SECRET_VALUE'
    env:
      SECRET_VALUE: $(XXX)
    name: step
```

Now, I do not get any error but `$SECRET_VALUE` seems not to be resolved. In the following step, where I get the output variable the content of `testvar` is `$SECRET_VALUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're using the inlining syntax to put the content of the secret directly in the script file, this requires the resulting script to be syntactically correct, and as you've figured out can cause interesting issues.

This is also a potential security issue, as people could also add a command to sent your secret by curl to a remote host for example.

It's therefore [safer to pass secrets as an environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables):

```
 - script: |
       echo "%MY_SECRET_VALUE%"
   env:
     MY_SECRET_VALUE: $(XXX)

 - bash: |
       echo "$MY_SECRET_VALUE"
   env:
     MY_SECRET_VALUE: $(XXX)
```

This has the added benefit that the secret itself isn't written to disk as part of the temporary script file. And it protect you against script injection attacks.

This is a better approach in general in the scripts, relying on the automatic environment variables for normal variables and explicit environment variables for secrets and more complex variable expressions.

Almost every task supports the extra `env:` section.

For bash, make sure you use `"` around the string you pass to echo, otherwise variables aren't expanded.

Comment: thank you for your comment: i do not get an error, but the output var seems not to get the resolved value (see my edits above)

Comment: Change `echo '...'` to `echo "..."`. Single quotes aren't expanded in bash.

Comment: Thats the solution
Please add to an answer so that I can accept!

Comment: Run your pipeline with diagnostics turned on to get better understanding what's happening, especially with the parsing of the magic command strings.